# Mysql : join three tables with cardinality 1:N

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database for an academy school. Its structure has three tables:
- The first one is a master of subjects. This table could have over 20 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `SUBJECTS` (
  `ID_SB` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_SB`)
)
```

-The second one contains students data. This one could have over 10000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `STUDENTS` (
  `ID_ST` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_ST`)
)
```

-The last one has the student's qualifications for each subject. It has around 1000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `QUALIFICATIONS` (
  `ID_CF` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_ST` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_SB` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VALUE` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_CF`)
)
```

I need to export all these data in excel format, something like:

`Id:st / Name / Subject1/ Subject2/ Subject3/ Subject4/..../Subject_N` (if one student has no qualification for a subject, excel show empty cell for this column).

How can I join all these tables? I have thought about using LEFT JOIN, but the number of returning rows for this query increases exponentially.

And now my problem is worse than before because I have to add new table related with students with 1:N cardinality.

How could I improve this functionality? I can't change the database schema.

Thanks

Comment: Exponentially? How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot `GROUP BY`, please try the following.

```
SELECT
    ST.ID_ST, ST.`NAME`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SU.`NAME`) AS subjects
FROM STUDENTS AS ST
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATIONS AS QU ON
    ST.ID_ST = QU.ID_ST
LEFT JOIN SUBJECTS AS SU ON
    SU.ID_SB = QU.ID_SB
GROUP BY ST.ID_ST
```

This should only display each student once, the subjects should be separated with comma(,) and each subject should only appear once per student (but only if the student has the subject).

ID - Name - Subjects
1 - Eve - Subj1, Subj3, Subj7

---

But, it wasn't what you asked for, you want each subject to have it's own column, right?

To do that, you could use a [`subquery`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) in the select to get all subjects and use [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) to print yes or no for each subject. You would still need to use the `GROUP_CONCAT`. But I would solve it in a different way.

I would use a different language to separate the columns. First you need the student information and ID for all the student subjects, like this:

```
SELECT
    ST.ID_ST, ST.`NAME`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT QU.`ID_SB`) AS subject_ids
FROM STUDENTS AS ST
LEFT JOIN QUALIFICATIONS AS QU ON
    ST.ID_ST = QU.ID_ST
GROUP BY ST.ID_ST
```

Then get the subjects:

```
SELECT * FROM SUBJECTS
```

The last part is creating the Excel. The example below is written in PHP:

```
$excelRows = array();
foreach($students as $student){
    $excelRow = array($student->id, $student->name);
    foreach($subjects as $subject){
        array_push($excelRow, (in_array($subject->id, $student->subject_ids))?'yes':'no');
    }
    array_push($excelRows, $excelRow);
}
```

So, we just loop the students, inside the student-loop we loop the subjects.

---

It isn't tested, but I think most of it should work. If it fails, please show me what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solution (green check) if it solved your problem - another way to say Thank you :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am rookie in stackoverflow.com. Now it's done. Thank you.